# Difference between Number() and toUpperCase() functions

Tags: javascript

Number() and toUpperCase() both look like functions but they can't be written in the same way.  I must be missing an obvious concept but I don't know what it is.

For example the following code works perfect.

```
var a = "cat";
var b = "dog";
console.log(a.toUpperCase() + b.toUpperCase());
```

The result is CATDOG.

But this code throws an error.

```
var a = 5;
var b = 10;
console.log(a.Number() + b.Number());
```

`a.Number is not a function`

And yet when I google Number() it is listed as a function.

[JavaScript Number() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp)

Interestingly when I reverse my code it throws an error.

```
a = "cat";
b = "dog";

console.log(toUpperCase(a) + toUpperCase(b));
```

`toUpperCase is not defined`

Number() reversed also works just fine.

```
a = 5;
b = 10;

console.log(Number(a) + Number(b));
```

Comment: you use `Number` as method of `Number`.

Comment: `Number()` is a global function. `a.Number` is an instance function.

Comment: and `toUpperCase` is part of `String.prototype` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read something about OOP (object-oriented programming).

Yes, `Number` is a function, but `a.Number` (meaning `int.Number`) is not. When you write `a.Number()`, you are calling the function `Number` of object `a` and that's not working because `integer` data type (`a` variable) does not have such function.

**EDIT:** (this is about OOP in general, not JavaScript-specific)

`Number` function is a **global function** which is sort of the base of any programming/scripting. It is defined somewhere and you can call it somewhere else. Additionaly you can pass arguments to it and it can return some value. For example:

```
function getHigherNumber(num) {
    return num + 1;
}

var foo = 5;
console.log(getHigherNumber(foo)); // writes "6"
```

The function getHigherNumber takes a number as an argument and returns it increased by one.

And then there are **methods** which are not global, but associated only to a datatype/class where they are defined. For example `string.toUpperCase()`. Here, "string" is a primitive datatype which also defines some methods (i.e. `toUpperCase`). Then you create an object `var bar = "some text";` and call the method on it: `bar.toUpperCase()` Notice the dot `.` between the object and its method you are calling.

Hope you understand it better now and sorry if some of my interpretations are not entirely accurate.

Comment: This is erroneous ... the variables used in `a.Number()` or `b.Number()` are **not** strings

Comment: @ Martin Heralecký Thanks Martin but if I change the code to `console.log(Number(a) + Number(b));` it works.  Why does it work written that way but not the first way?  Interestingly when I write `console.log(toUpperCase(a) + toUpperCase(b));` this also throws an error.

Comment: @DR01D I added some more explanation. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Martin Heralecký   Thanks now I understand!  But if `string.toUpperCase()` is a method why does it need the `()` if it's not used to pass variables?  For instance `string.toUpperCase` throws an error but `string.toUpperCase()` works fine.  Shouldn't only functions need the `()` since they pass variables?

Comment: @DR01D Both functions and methods may or may not take arguments. It only depends on how are they defined. The "unnecessary" `()` at functions/methods that take no arguments is just a matter of the language syntax. There could be a language where you don't need to write `()` when no arguments passed...

Comment: @Martin Heralecký Awesome!  Do you know of a simple example where a method uses an argument?  For example object.method(???).  What is something an argument might do in a method?

Comment: @DR01D For example: `var foo = "Hello, World"; console.log(foo.substring(7));` which writes "World".

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the link you posted, it refers to Function and not method.
You can use method on object that provides it.

For example:

`toUpperCase` is a method because it is provided in String.prototype. So you can use in

```
"Prova".toUppercase();
```

Because `"Prova"` inherits the method from String.prototype

`toFixed` is a method because it is provided in Number.prototype. So you can use in this way

```
var x = 9.656;
x.toFixed(0);
```

Function looks like a simple definition of block of code:

```
function myUpperCase(myString) {
   return myString.toUpperCase(myString);
}
```

Then, in your code, you can use it in this way:

```
myUpperCase("cat");
```

Comment: super interesting!  So one is a function and the other is a method.  Is there an obvious way to tell them apart or is this a case of lots of memorization?

Comment: You should detect it on your goal. For instance: If you have a Car Object with `status` attribute, and you want change it,  you should implement a method in Car Object ( changeStatus(newStatus) Car.changeStatus("active") ). Instead, if you have two Car Object with `price` attribute and you want sum the values, you can create a method ( `function sumCarPrice(Car1, Car2) { return Car1.price + Car2.price); }` )

Answer (score 1):

```
String.prototype.toUpperCase();
```

is a function that is built into the string prototype as a method. Hence, it is called with the following syntax:

```
String.toUpperCase();
```

On the other hand,

```
Number();
```

is a function that is natively built into the JavaScript language. Since it is not defined as a method, it is not invoked as one when invoked.

Comment: @lqueso101 Thanks I think I might be making some headway.  So Number() is a function and toUpperCase() is a method?  Should I memorize the different functions and methods or is there an obvious pattern that makes it easy to differentiate the two?